# Построить гистограмму распределения целевой переменной и рассчитать коэффициент наклона

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, искусственный-интеллект, seaborn

Нужно построить гистограмму распределения целевой переменной и рассчитать коэффициент наклона. У меня есть кусок с датасета и описание каждой с переменных

```
import pandas as pd
ind = [5375, 11681, 5325, 679, 12625, 8090, 11518, 16341, 2607,1742]
dats = {
'index' : [5376, 11682, 5326, 680, 12626, 8091, 11519, 16342, 2608,1743],
'date': [2011-8-16, 2012-5-6,2011-8-14,2011-1-31,2012-6-15,2011-12-8, 2011-4-30,2012-11-18, 2011-4-23,2011-3-18],
'season': [4,3,4,2,3,1,3,1,3,2],
'yr': [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
'mnth': [8,5,8,1,6,12,4,11,4,3],
'hr': [21,22,19,15,6,18,3,15,13,7],
'holiday': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'weekday': [2,0,0,1,5,4,1,0,6,5],
'workingday': [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
'weathersit': [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'temp':[0.72,0.56,0.72,0.16,0.54,0.28,0.40,0.42,0.52,0.4],
'atemp': [0.6667, 0.5303, 0.6970, 0.1818, 0.5152, 0.2727, 0.4091, 0.4242, 0.5000, 0.4091],
'hum':[0.54, 0.73, 0.74, 0.59, 0.83, 0.52, 0.76, 0.54, 0.83, 0.66],
'windspeed': [0.0000, 0.1642, 0.2239, 0.1343, 0.1343, 0.2239, 0.1642, 0.2836, 0.3881, 0.1940],
'cnt': [215, 157, 259, 44, 151, 318, 4, 407, 312, 123]
```

}

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=dats, index=ind)
```

[image: ОПИСАНИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ]

Был бы признателен за объяснение какая тут целевая переменная и как хотя бы примерно это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вы решили проверить нашу эрудицию? Ну типа вам задали домашнее задание, но вы то на занятии были заняты чем-то другим более интересным. Учителя не слушали. А теперь хотите, что бы мы УГАДАЛИ, что вам задали? Ладно, если вы так просите, могу сделать ПРЕДПОЛОЖЕНИЕ, что целевой переменной тут выступает количество вызовов скорой помощи, а исследуется зависимость этой величины от некоторых погодных факторов.

Это "примерно" делается так -  гистограмма строиться в библиотеке matplotlib с помощью функции hist(), в seaborne - функцией distplot(), в pandas -  тоже методом .hist().

Что вы имеете ввиду под "коэффициентом наклона" - мне не ведомо, но если это коэффициент скоса -  то в pandas он рассчитывается с помощью метода .skew().

Удачи.